# What is the difference between Index Out of Range Exception and Index Outside the Bounds of Array Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, exception, c#-2.0

Is there any difference between "Index was out of range exception" and "Index was outside the bounds of the array exception"?

Answer (score 10):

**They're exactly the same thing.**

[`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) is the *name* of the exception class that is thrown. Its *description* is given by Visual Studio as "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

This exception is thrown when an attempt is made to access an element of an array with an index that is outside of the bounds of the array.

Note that the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` class is not part of C# at all, but rather the Java language (or Microsoft's implementation, J#).